# how to make a CSS animation end point the right edge of the browser

Tags: css, css-animations

i'm trying to mimic a loading function for this animation, so i want the end point of the animation to be the top right edge of the browser.

how do i do this? ie what can i replace "left:1000" with to always be the top right edge of the browser.

```
.square {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: colors 2s;
    -webkit-animation: colors 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes colors {
    0% {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }

    99% {
        left: 1000px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colors {
    0% {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }

    99% {
        left: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's easier if your element's position is `absolute` (then we can animate the `right` instead), because it's relative, we can't know the exact **initial** location and the `left` is just the offset from this location (not offset from the left edge of the container).

Comment: @KingKing okay! so if it's absolute then would it be right: 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to use both `left` and `margin-left`

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EKf67/)

```
.square
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: colors 2s;
    -webkit-animation: colors 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left:-30px;
}

@keyframes colors {
    0% {left: 30px;}
    99% { left: 100%;} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes colors {
    0% {left: 30px;}
    99% { left: 100%;} 
}
```

Comment: this is great. thank you! if i the wanted to mimic YT's directly, so the left edge of the line in anchored and the right edge gets longer instead of moving, how would i do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EKf67/1/ @rs202 even simpler, you just need to animate `width`

Comment: Note that this works because your have the square located right at the beginning of a line, if it's located somewhere else like in this case http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/EKf67/2/ , it can't work. That's why I said `relative` made it hard to solve when the initial location is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute;` and `right:0` will take you to the right edge of the browser.

```
.square{
    position:absolute;
}

@keyframes colors{
    from{
        left:0;
        top: 0px;
    }

    to{
        right:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm just did that and the animation seems to have stopped. any ideas?

Comment: @rs202 sorry for not responding sooner. The animation is infinite right? So try instead of `left:0` in the from, try `right:100%`.

Answer (score 0):

After running this, I am assuming you're trying to do something like how YouTube has that loading bar. If so, trying adding this line to your ".square" class.

```
top: 0px;
```

And then just remove the "relative" positioning, and change it to "fixed".

Hope that helps, but might not even be related to your problem.